# .htaccess on small catalog page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I building small catalog webpage. So I have a problem with this. When I put this code in .htacess

```
RewriteRule ^katalog$ /katalog.php
RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)$ /vrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1
RewriteRule ^katalog1/(.*)/(.*)$ /podvrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2
RewriteRule ^katalog2/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /proizvod.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2&katalog_id=$3&katalog_seo=$4
```

my catalog works fine, bit is not pretty to see with that numbers included. But if I go this way it don't work.

```
RewriteRule ^katalog$ /katalog.php
RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)$ /vrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1
RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)/(.*)$ /podvrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2
RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /proizvod.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2&katalog_id=$3&katalog_seo=$4
```

I wish to get something like this

```
http://www.500maniac.com/katalog/vocne-sadnice/smokva/76/petrovaca-bijela
```

not this

```
http://www.500maniac.com/katalog2/vocne-sadnice/smokva/76/petrovaca-bijela
```

First time working on something like this so I nedd little help! If it's not clear ask and i will answer.

Answer (score 0):

. will match the /, so try replace (.*) with

```
([^/]*)
```

like this:

```
RewriteRule ^katalog1/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2
```

Here's .my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^katalog/([^/]*)$ /index.php?vrsta_seo=$1
RewriteRule ^katalog/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2
```

and in index.php

```
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

If visit http://localhost.com/katalog/ccccc/zzzzz, the output is:

```
string(34) "vrsta_seo=ccccc&podvrsta_seo=zzzzz"
```

Comment: It work with your code but $KatalogVrstaSeo = $_GET['vrsta_seo']; from ?vrsta_seo=$1 return empty variable.

Comment: Try var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) and see what the final url?

Comment: Also ([^/]+) might be better

Comment: On RewriteRule ^katalog([^/]+)([^/]+)$ /podvrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2 var_dump return empty, on RewriteRule ^katalog1([^/]+)([^/]+)$ /podvrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2 show whats in variable.

Comment: Not ^katalog([^/]+)([^/]+)$ , but ^katalog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$(keep the /)

Comment: I change to katalog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ but still nothing in variable. Thanks for trying!

Comment: well, it works for me, with RewriteRule ^katalog/([^/]*)$ /index.php?vrsta_seo=$1, I access http://localhost/katalog/ccccc the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is "vrsta_seo=ccccc"

Comment: works for me here RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)$ /vrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1, but not here RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)/(.*)$ /podvrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2

Comment: mybe is a problem tha I have vrsta.php i podvrsta.php?

Answer (score 0):

Have your rules like this  in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(katalog1|katalog2)$ /katalog [L]

RewriteRule ^katalog$ /katalog.php [L]

RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)$ /vrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)/(.*)$ /podvrsta.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^katalog/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /proizvod.php?vrsta_seo=$1&podvrsta_seo=$2&katalog_id=$3&katalog_seo=$4 [L]
```